# datatables.net удаление содержания строки из базы данных по нажатию кнопки

Tags: php, jquery, sql, база-данных

Есть скрипт от [datatables.net](https://datatables.net), создающий таблицу из элементов существующей базы данных.

Нуждаестя в подготовленной в HTML таблице и работает вот так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').DataTable( {
                "pageLength": 25,
                "language": {
                    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/German.json"
                },

                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,

                "ajax": "server_processing.php",


                 "columns": [
                    { "data": "MAC-Adresse" },
                    { "data": "Name" },
                    { "data": "Vorname" },
                    { "data": "Klasse" },
                    { "data": "Update-Typ" },
                    { "data": "Gtyp" },
                    { "data": "Info" },
                    { "defaultContent": "<div align=\"center\"> <button class=\"btn btn-success\" id=\"done\">Fertig</button> <button class=\"btn btn-danger\" id=\"fire\">Verstecken</button></div>" 
                    }
                    ]
            });

            //button 1
            $('#example tbody').on( 'click', '#done', function () {
                if (confirm("Удалить строку?")){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "del.php"
                });
                success: alert("Строка удалена.");
            }

            });

            //button 2
            $('#example tbody').on('click', '#fire', function () {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            });

        } );
```

По нажатию кнопки #fire скрывает соответствующую строку.

По нажатию кнопки #done должно удалиться содержимое соответствующей строки строки из базы данных и обновиться таблица.

Начал писать del.php и упёрся в проблему:

```
$result = mysql_query("DELETE * FROM main WHERE Какое тут условие?);
```

Серверная часть создания таблицы:

server_processing.php

```
header('content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');  
$_GET['search']['value']=htmlentities($_GET['search']['value'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
$primaryKey = 'MAC-Adresse';
$table = 'main';
$columns = array(
array( 'db' => 'MAC-Adresse', 'dt' => 'MAC-Adresse' ),
array( 'db' => 'Name',        'dt' => 'Name' ),
array( 'db' => 'Vorname',     'dt' => 'Vorname' ),
array( 'db' => 'Klasse',      'dt' => 'Klasse' ),
array( 'db' => 'Update-Typ',  'dt' => 'Update-Typ' ),
array( 'db' => 'Gtyp',        'dt' => 'Gtyp' ),
array( 'db' => 'Info',        'dt' => 'Info' ),
array( 'db' => 'Bearbeiten',  'dt' => 'Bearbeiten' )
);
$sql_details = array(
'user' => 'root',
'pass' => '',
'db'   => 'devices',
'host' => 'localhost'
);
require( 'ssp.class.php' );
echo json_encode(
SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
```

И ссылка на [ssp.class.php](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php)

Comment: `DELETE FROM main WHERE MAC-Adresse=?` - это запрос. И он ровно так должен выглядеть, чтобы работать в php. MAC-Adresse только экранируйте тильдой. В аякс соответственно нужно мак передать, а на сервере подставить значение

Comment: При формировании таблицы в `html`, формируйте у каждый `tr`, какой-либо дата-атрибут, по которому вы потом сможете написать ваше условие в запросе delete.